# How do I serve CSS to Django in development?

Tags: python, django

I've been all through the documentation, and it just doesn't make sense to me.  I ran collectstatic, I set up /static/ directories in both my app and my project directories, I added STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT to my settings.py file (but I have no idea how to know if they're set correctly) and {{ STATIC_URL }} still isn't rendering out to anything. It all seems like a heck of a lot of overkill just to connect html to css.

I think I'm lost in the details; could anyone supply a high-level breakdown of this static files idea? I'm afraid I may have mixed instructions for both production and development setups.

MORE: Here's the relevant bit from my settings.py file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'dashboard.base',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
)

STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    'C:/Users/Sean/Desktop/Work Items/dashboard/base/static/',
)
```

And this is the code I'm trying to use in my template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/960.css" />
```

OK. I made the changes everybody recommended. Here's my new urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from base.views import show_project
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
# Example:
# (r'^dashboard/', include('dashboard.foo.urls')),

# Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
# (r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
('^show_project/$', show_project),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True }),
        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True }))

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Am I missing something? Usually my problems turn out to be something really basic that CS pros take for granted but I miss.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how mine is setup. It sounds like you might be missing the static context processor?

**STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL**

In the settings.py used in development:

```
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

And the settings.py used on my production server:

```
STATIC_URL = '//static.MYDOMAIN.com/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/USER/public_html/static.MYDOMAIN.com/'
```

So, all the static files are located in `static/`. On the production server, all these files in `static/` are collected to `/home/USER/public_html/static.MYDOMAIN.com/` where they are served by a different web server (nginx in my case) and not Django. In other words, my django application (running on Apache) never even receives requests for static assets in production.

**CONTEXT PROCESSOR**

In order for templates to have the `STATIC_URL` variable available to them, you need to use the `django.core.context_processors.static` context processor, also defined in `settings.py`:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    # other context processors....
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    # other context processors....
)
```

**SERVER STATIC ASSETS IN DEVELOPMENT**

Django doesn't get requests for static assets in production, however, in development we just let Django serve our static content. We use `staticfiles_urlpatterns` in `urls.py` to tell Django to serve requests for `static/*`.

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
# .... your url patterns are here ...
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Comment: Thanks - I have the processor - you can see it in my file above. Your settings did help me, though: I was using absolute paths in my STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL settings. I've fixed it but I think I still need absolute paths in the STATICFILES_DIRS, right?

Comment: @StormShadow, you could do `os.path.join(os.dirname(__file__),"static")`, assuming your static files are in the same directory as the `settings.py`.

Comment: I think that you don't mention if you are serving your files using the Django development server or another server like nginx or Apache. If the second the issue could be related to the configuration of your production server not to the configuration settings in your project.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Serving static files in development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development). You need to define the `STATIC_URL` and `STATICFILES_DIRS` to let `django.contrib.staticfiles` know where to look for files.

Comment: Right. That's what I'm going off of right now, actually. But it isn't working. I'm using forward slashes and starting the paths at C:/. Is that wrong?

Comment: Incidentally, they're both set to the same thing since I don't know which actually sets the {{ STATIC_URL }} variable. Neither seem to be working.

Comment: They shouldn't be the same. STATICFILES_DIRS should be where your files are currently, STATIC_ROOT should be a separate folder where you want your files to end up when they are collected, and STATIC_URL should be the path you want to use to access your files when using your site/app

Answer (score 2):

The idea behind the static files idea is that you can distribute your development related media file (css/js etc.) on a per-app basis, and allow the static files application to manage and collect all these resources from their various places.

So you tell the static files app where to look for static files (by settings STATICFILES_DIRS), where to copy to them (STATIC_ROOT) and what path to access them (STATIC_URL). When you run collectstatic, it search through the directories and copies all the files it finds into the static root.

The benefit of this is that you can manage your static files on a finer leve:

```
project/app1/static/css/ # These are css/js for a particular app
project/app2/static/css/
project/app3/static/css/
project/static/css # These might be general css/js for the whole project
static/ # This is where the collectstatic command will copy files to
```

and after you collectstatic them you will have:

```
project/app1/static/css/
project/app2/static/css/
project/app3/static/css/
project/static/css

static/app1/css/
static/app2/css/
static/app3/css/
static/css/
```

When you put your app/site on a production server, you let the webserver (apache, nginx) deal with serving the files by telling it to serve media files at /static/ or /media/ directly, while passing all other requests to the application. When developing though, it's easier to let the development server do this for you.

To do this, you have explicitly tell is server any request for media under /static/ (your STATIC_URL). In your urls.py, put the following (or similar)

```
from django.conf import settings
...
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True }),
        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True }))
```

Comment: Yeah that doesn't work either. It gives me "NameError at /show_project/
name 'settings' is not defined"

Comment: Thanks! But still coming up with nothing. I just pasted the other code I've got in there right now. Maybe I've forgotten something in that?

Comment: Like I said in the other comment, STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT shouldn't be the same. STATIC_ROOT need's to 'static/' or similar

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and search many answers, but no one give me right answer.
The problem is you don't use [RequestContext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext) I think.
You should make a [RequestContext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext) as the parameter of Template like

```
c = RequestContext(request, {
    'foo': 'bar',
})
```

In my views is:

```
return render_to_response('parts/test2.html', RequestContext(request, locals()))
```